How to play notification with custom sound that is downloaded by the app after it was installed?
I am working on an iOS app (an alarm clock), where I need to play a custom notification sound that is downloaded by the app after it has been installed. Here's the relevant part of the code:
let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
...
notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: myLocalFile)

This works fine when myLocalFile is part of the app bundle, but I need to play sounds that are downloaded by the app. Here's some additional context:

The app generates custom AI sounds for alarms that are specific to the user.
The app downloads these sounds and needs to play them when the alarm triggers.
The alarm must play in all scenarios where the phone is on, including:

Foreground and background
Screen lock
After reboot


Ideally, I'd like to display a full-screen alarm UI (but haven’t been able to figure out how to do this). Any guidance on that would be appreciated as well.
For now, I am simulating the alarm using a notification, but I am limited to playing sounds from the app bundle.

How can I play these downloaded custom sounds in the notification, and is there a way to achieve a full-screen alarm UI?

Since notifications can't use downloaded sounds, one option is to manually play the downloaded sound when the notification is triggered.
I observe the notification using UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate and play the sound manually using AVAudioPlayer. Example:
// Observe when the notification is received
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification, 
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    // Play the downloaded sound manually
    playDownloadedSound()

    // Complete with notification options (vibration, badge, etc.)
    completionHandler([.badge, .banner, .list])
}

func playDownloadedSound() {
    guard let soundURL = // URL to your downloaded sound
    else { return }

    do {
        let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
        player.play()
    } catch {
        print("Error playing sound: \(error)")
    }
}

